# Linux Commandline Combining files

Tags: linux, command-line, cat, ls

For a command like this,

```
ls -rt | tail -n 100
```

Will give the latest modified 100 files. What commandline tool should be used to pipe the result of this query to, so that all the filenames that is shows are copied to a single file. eg:

If a folder has 100 files, the above command will give me all the filenames. I want to copy all the data in all the files to a single 101th file. How do I do it?

Commandline to `cat` each file to the destination is what I am looking for. But I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ls -rt | tail -n 100 | xargs cat > file`

1. The `xargs` command repeatedly reads text from its standard input stream, constructs a command-line using that text, then executes the command line.
2. `xags cat` means that it treats each line of input text as a separate argument, and constructs a `cat` command using each input line as an argument to the `cat` command. It will construct as long a command-line as it can, so it will fork the minimum number of `cat` processes.
3. The `cat` processes therefore read the files you are interested in, and write their content, in order, to the standard output stream.
4. `> file` puts that text into the result file

Answer (score 2):

I found this simple enough:

```
cat `ls -rt | tail -n 100` > singleFile
```

Comment: Breaks for file names with spaces in them, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have filenames with spaces in them I would suggest using GNU find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%Ts %p\n' \
| sort -nr       \
| head -n100     \
| cut -d' ' -f2- \
| tr '\n' '\0'   \
| xargs -0 cat > outfile
```

The `printf` argument to `find` inserts last modification time in seconds in front of the pathname, which `sort` sorts in descending order, `head` takes the first 100 files, `cut` removes the modification timestamp, `tr` zero delimits the file list and `xargs` passes the filenames correctly to `cat`.

Note, this doesn't work if the filenames have newlines in them.